# Django admin directory on Debian

Tags: python, django, templates, debian, admin

Where can I find my Django admin template files (I am running Django on Debian)?

I tried to look here:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

But I can only get as far as /usr/lib. When I try to access python2.6 using `cd` command, I get message that it is not a directory.

I would appreciate any help :).

Comment: You might not be using python 2.6? Try 2.7

Comment: I don't know why I could not get in there before. Anyway - I got into python2.6, but the directory consists only of .py and .pyc files - no directories and definitely no sites-packages.

In /lib I also have python-django folder, but it does not have what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo updatedb
locate django/contrib/admin/media/
```

Comment: Try running: "sudo apt-get install mlocate" Then see if you can do updatedb

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated db and located the django folder in:
    /usr/share/pyshared

Answer (score 1):

Go into the terminal and try this command...

```
python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print get_python_lib()"
```

This should inform you as to your site-packages location.

Comment: It showed:
    /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
But inside there are only the following files:
    debconf.py  debconf.pyc  python-support.pth  README

Answer (score 0):

say if you want to see where a package -- say PIL -- is installed, get to a python shell, type:

```
>>> import PIL
>>> help(PIL)
```

The help file looks like:

```
Help on package PIL:

NAME
    PIL

FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py

...
```

now I know that PIL is in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/

alternatively,

```
>>> print PIL.__file__
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.pyc
```